# How do change javascript cookie from 15 day count to manually do a new cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies, colorbox

I'm implementing a script with Colorbox which shows a nice popup the first time a user visits a website. This script that I found is setting the cookie to last for 15 days - what I want is to manually be able to manage the "cookie-update" by my own. In my case I want to use this script to show the user that my website has been updated and using the Colorbox to show the changelog; just on the first visit. Something like this:

- Update #1 -> New cookie tells there's a new update -> Show Colorbox 1 time -> Then no more, until...
- Update #2 -> New cookie tells there's a new update -> Show Colorbox -> ...and so on...

Short version of the question: How do I change the script from a 15 day timer to manually be able to change it so I can decide when I want to show my Colorbox with a new changelog?

The original script is located here:
http://papermashup.com/automatic-jquery-site-subscription-lightbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a date in the site - Note JS months start at zero

[DEMO](http://plungjan.name/SO/testoverlay1.html)

```
var latestUpdate=new Date(2012,11,10).getTime(); // 10th of December
var whatVersionSeen = parseInt($.cookie("visited"));
if (isNaN(whatVersionSeen)) whatVersionSeen = 0; // first time
if (whatVersionSeen < latestUpdate) { // whatever in the cookie < latest update
  $.cookie('visited', latestUpdate, { expires: 365 });
  $.colorbox({width:"580px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe_popup"});
}
```

the above code replaces

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
  var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;
  var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
  document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
  $.colorbox({width:"580px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe_popup"});
 }
```

completely and expects to find [$.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Comment: Said and done, thank you! You meant 2012,12,15 instead of 2012,11,15 right? How can I check that this really works? I tried to set the date to 2012,12,9 but nothing happens.

Comment: I understand. I tried to set the date to 2012,10,10 and cleared my cookies but nothing happens. jquery.cookie.js is loaded with jquery-1.7.2.min.js. I just replaced the old code with the code you wrote above. Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: No matter what I set (past, today, future) nothing happens. I tried to put it the first way you wrote (2012,11,15) but the Colorbox isn't appearing...

Comment: Must say I really appreciate your help here, thank you! But with the code you wrote above the Colorbox appears, but on EVERY page refresh I do... I want it to show on just the first visit. What's NaN btw?

Answer (score 0):

There is Jquery Code in that Script.

```
$("document").ready(function (){ 

       // load the overlay

        if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
            var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;
            var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
            document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
            $.colorbox({width:"580px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe_popup"});
        }

        $(".open_popup").colorbox({width:"580px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe_popup"});

 });
```

if you want to change the days then change it here.

```
var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;
```

Comment: I figured that out, but I don't want a timer at all, I wan't to manually be able to decide when a new cookie should be delivered so the Colorbox shows with an updated changelog. I updated my first post with a better description of the question.

Comment: who needs to decide ? the visitor or admin ?

Comment: Me/the developer, not the user. When I update the code to my server I want to simply be able to change something that triggers a new cookie -> show the Colorbox (on the users first visit). Something like this: New update -> I edit something in the code which brings new cookie -> Show Colorbox for user (on the first  visit).

Comment: as this is jquery you cannot do dynamically . for that you need to go and change the code and upload to server.

Comment: It's okey for me to change the code every time I want to announce a new update, but I do I do it? As I mentioned; I don't want the timer functionality...

Comment: just change this to var fifteenDays = 0; if you want to make this without time bases

Comment: With that setting it now shows EVERY time I enter the site. I only want to show it at the first visit. And when there's a new update I want to change something in the code so the Colorbox shows at the first visit (since the new update) again. To explain it once more I want the functionality to be like this: I've done a new update to my website -> I do _something_ that triggers a new cookie -> Show Colorbox for user on first visit. The same procedure when I do a new update.

Comment: then make it for more days. make it for 1year. var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*365; and in between if you change this then reset that again.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question. With your suggestion - how should I do if I want to show Colorbox with a new update if the timer is set to one year? A new update may come within a week or so... That's my problem, I want to "trigger" a NEW cookie in some way when there is a NEW update that I want to show to the user.

Comment: okay.. i guess there is another answer to ur question. try that jquery Cookie